# Mysql Foreign key acting as index or not

Tags: mysql

I just started working on query performance optimisation. I understood some concept of `explain` keyword and using it to analyse the query.

Confusion :
So we have a read replica and a production server.

In production :
Lets say there is a table where we have columns `column_a,column_b,column_c`. Here `column_b` is a foreign key and is defined like

`` CONSTRAINT `FK_COL_B` FOREIGN KEY (`column_b`) REFERENCES `another_table` (`id`), ``

Now, lets say we have a query_x, where we are querying on this column. When I do `explain query_x`. It says possible keys as `FK_COL_B` and show this key being used in `key column`. But the rows column shows 7015 rows mapped with this and filtered % is only 10%.

Where as in Read Replica :

I actually added this column as an index explicitly. There the query shows much better performance. Filtered percentage is also 100% there.

So all I wanted to understand is that if query plan shows a foreign key constraing as eligible keys/key used, is it different from a explicit key defined on the same column ?

Thanks.

Comment: FK creates an `INDEX`.  The Optimizer _may_ use the index for performance.  For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: (And take the stackoverflow tutorial; it will give you an easy 100 rep points, making it easier to interact with us.)

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, a foreign key requires an index, full stop. If an index doesn't exist in the table, an index is created automatically when you declare the foreign key.

The name of such an automatically-generated index is the same as the name of the foreign key constraint. That might lead to some confusion about the EXPLAIN report, because it appears that the FK constraint is used for the optimization, when in fact it is the index.

I think you misunderstand what `filtered` means in the EXPLAIN.

Queries search for rows by index lookup, and this creates a set of rows that match a condition. These are the "rows examined," reported in the `rows` field of the EXPLAIN. But the query may have other conditions that are not supported by any index lookup. The query has to evaluate every examined row against the other conditions, and filter out some of these.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column_b = 1234 AND column_a = 5678;
```

Suppose the query uses an index on `column_b`, matches 1000 rows, and then the `filtered` field says 10%. This means out of the 1000 rows matched by the index for the first search term, 10% pass the condition in the second search term on `column_a`, but 90% are discarded. So the end result of the query is estimated to be 100 rows (of course the EXPLAIN is only a rough estimate made before any rows have actually been read, so the actual results will vary).

So a low value for `filtered` actually indicates that the query is doing a lot of work evaluating rows that will be discarded. A high value of `filtered` (like 100%) indicates that the rows examined after index lookup is roughly the same set of rows that ultimately are returned.

I seldom use the `filtered: 100%` as a guide to change anything. You might think it means my second term of my search is a waste, since it must evaluate that condition for all 1000 rows matched by the index lookup, for no net change. But that's not true, because the EXPLAIN is only an estimate, and in the real data, there are a few rows that must be eliminated by my second term. A query that returns a result that only roughly accurate is pretty useless. What this means is that `filtered: 100%` doesn't help us understand how to change the query or the indexing.

But `filtered: 10%` might indicate that we could have made an index to narrow down the examined rows first, so the ultimate result set might have been produced more efficiently. In this example, by making a compound index on `(column_b, column_a)`.